# How to switch the editor in mc (midnight commander) from nano to mcedit?

Tags: 10.10, command-line, configuration, editor, nano

Using ubuntu 10.10 the editor in mc (midnight commander) is nano. How can i switch to the internal mc editor (mcedit)?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Press the following keys in order, one at a time:

1. <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + 9</kbd>  Activates the top menu.
2. <kbd>o</kbd>  Selects the `Option` menu.
3. <kbd>c</kbd>  Opens the configuration dialog.
4. <kbd>i</kbd>  Toggles the `use internal edit` option.
5. <kbd>s</kbd>  Saves your preferences.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you also add how to change the editor to any other editor?

Comment: It would be better to specify a way to change this from the command line, but not by changing the OS default editor.

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to do the same in the command line, say, by adding/changing an environment variable? I'd like to automate this.

Comment: Looks it has changed to 't' instead of 'i' [image](http://imgur.com/rQi0rrm)

Comment: @trusktr to change to other editor you need to uncheck the option and [set the `EDITOR` environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80852/209677), easily with [`select-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/486205/349837)

Answer (score 64):

Run MC as usual.
On the command line right above the bottom row of menu selections type `select-editor`.
This should open a menu with a list of all of your installed editors.
This is working for me on all my current linux machines.

Comment: Thank you! That was the only solution that worked for me with the mc version in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get a "Command not found" error from Bash.

Comment: This solution is useful in Ubuntu (not tested in Debian) but in Redhat or Centos you need to do something like this blog [rhel-centos-set-default-editor-to-nano](http://rizwanansari.net/rhel-centos-set-default-editor-to-nano/)

Comment: @hermeslm, Thank you ^_^

Comment: +1 as this works in Debian 11 as well *and* allows one to change the editor to eg nano after mcedit was selected, as Debian activates mcedit as an external editor so changing it becomes impossible with the menu-based solution given by Isaiah.

Answer (score 21):

You can also change the standard editor system-wide. Open a terminal and type this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

You will get a list of the installed editors on your system, and you can choose your favorite.

Comment: OP is not asking how to change the system default editor.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson yes, but changing the default system editor would also change the default external MC editor, thus answering the OP's question. It's still a valid answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to leave mc and system settings as it is now, you may just run it like

```
$ EDITOR=mcedit mc
```

Answer (score 4):

In user's home folder (`/home/<user-name>/`) there should be a file named `.selected_editor`. One can edit it and change it there to a desired editor.

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/path/to/mcedit"
```

Or remove this file to force MC to ask about default editor on first edit.

Comment: This is the best way to also set a custom editor like `micro`.

Comment: This is the way it worked for me as mc is not showing the "save" option

Answer (score 2):

Open Midnight Commander, go to Options -> Configuration and check "use internal editor"
Hit save and you are done.