# How to set up Micro editor as the default editor in Midnight Commander

Tags: midnight-commander

I want to setup `micro` as the default editor in Midnight Commander (I was using the default `nano`). I've installed micro as a snap.

I deleted the file `.selected_editor` in my home user folder so now it gives me a list of editors each time that I press <kbd>F4</kbd>, but micro does not appear in this list.

```
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  3. /usr/bin/mcedit
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  5. /usr/bin/code
  6. /bin/ed

Choose 1-6 [1]:
```

What can I do to make micro my default editor?

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS, my terminal is Terminator and my Micro version is 2.0.6.

Comment: Have you tried instead of removing `.selected_editor` to put the binary of your editor in it manually?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I tried to put `SELECTED EDITOR="/var/lib/snapd/snaps/micro_2596.snap"` in the file; but it gives me an error`/usr/bin/sensible-editor: 25: /usr/bin/sensible-editor: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/micro_2596.snap: Permission denied`. Then sets the default editor back to nano.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the correct way to launch a snap, but I don't use snaps. You would have to put the same command line you would use in a terminal to start it.

Comment: I got it working by typing the `micro` command in the path of the editor. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. I will post it as an answer so it is more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use another editor than those proposed by mc, just choose any of the options so mc creates the `~/.selected_editor` file.

Then edit that file and replace the path to the executable in it to the editor you want to use. You need to use a command line that would also work in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/) (for e.g., with [brew](https://brew.sh/)).
2. [Disable mc internal editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/16782/349837).
3. Use `select-editor` command (already there, from sensible-utils package; instead of editing any file directly).